# How to hide UINavigationBar when using TTNavigator (Three20 v1.0a2)

Tags: iphone, hide, uinavigationbar, three20, ttnavigator

I want to hide the UINavigationBar in a TTViewController presented by TTNavigator.

Is there a way to archive this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do this in Three20 as you would do in a project without Three20. Like so:

```
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Hop this helps.

Comment: "self.navigationController" seems to be nil when using TTNavigator and TTViewController. But your Question about "TTNavigator popViewController?" directed me to the solution => [[TTNavigator navigator].topViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

Comment: `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];` works for me when called in viewLoad.